# SetText at fixed rate

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

I want to `SetText` at `fixedRate` with handler post delay, but I cannot do this because it I get the error that I can't change text in a thread different from main thread.

I have a static text stored in a different class that changes it and I want to set the text of the `TextView` to this text every 100 milliseconds.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In android you are supposed to manipulated UI elements only on the UI Thread. You can use asynctask, hander or runOnUiThread to achieve this. The later is the simplest:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        textview.setText("some text");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Schedule a timer to do the task..

```
private static class UpdateText extends TimerTask {
            private final TextView tv;

            public UpdateText(TextView tv) {
                this.tv = tv;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                tv.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText(tv.getText() + "Append here");
                    }
                });
            }
```

In `onCreate` do this

```
tv.setText("Append here");
        setContentView(tv);

        Timer timing = new Timer();
        timing.schedule(new UpdateText(tv), 3000, 3000);
```